# Setting materials correctly after importing from Daz3D

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

As following pictures shown, I imported Daz3D scene in Blender and found that textures of parts are messed up in Blender 2.8.2. From the rendered image (Cycles), I can see following:

- In Blender (Cycles), some parts rendered were washed up while the other parts (e.g., wall color) are darker.
- Hair is not glossy, translucent, nor reflective.
- pool water is not blue although its texture looks variant.

I tried various material properties and node parameters in vain. So my question as a novice is simple one: Can the rendered image from Daz3D Iray be achieved in Blender Cycles?

**Iray from Daz3D**
[image: Daz]

**Cycle from Blender**
[image: Blender]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: @Timaroberts No, I don't think it answers my question. I imported Daz3D file directly and I understand importing materials would not be perfect. My question is whether original rendering is possible by changing proper properties and parameters in Blender.

Comment: May I ask the reason for downvote? Did I violate some rule in this site?

Comment: I would presume that it is because your question does not show much research. Have you tried to replicate the scene with cycles materials? If so, what do you have so far?